# Interpretation of Pearson Correlation Test in R

Tags: r

While Computing Correlation in R, I get the following output.
The correlation represents correlation between profits and assets.

[image]

I understand P-value and t. However, I have no idea what df refers to.

P.S.I am sorry, if this is wrong forum.

Thanks.

Comment: you might also want to check out http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` stands for `degrees of freedom`  (not `data.frame`)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)